# Converting Escaped Literals to Specials with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I want to have a text input which users are able to enter special characters such as **\n**.
However when I try to get the value inside the input I get the escaped string. I need to unescape the value or any workarounds?

**EDIT**: I put an example http://jsfiddle.net/9hmHr/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
<textarea id="x">hello\ndolly</textarea>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('x').value.replace(/\\n/g,'\n'))">Click</button>
```

[**Demo forked from your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qraBJ/)

```
var str = 'aaasddd';

alert(
  str.replace('s', 
    $('#my').val().replace(/\\n/g,'\n')
  )
);
```

Comment: I edited my question and put an example as you wished, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting way to do this after searching a while for a more well-rounded solution, that didn't involve replacing every character with its literal form.

```
var x = "\\thello\\n\\tworld",
    y = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(x).replace(/\\\\/g,'\\')
    );

console.log("Original:");
console.log(x);

console.log("Literal:");
console.log(y);
```

The above outputs:

```
Original:
\thello\n\tworld

Literal:
    hello
    world
```

I hope this helps!

**NOTE**: This may not work with strings that may contain braces (`{` or `}`) as it may attempt to convert it into an object literal. You may be able to avoid this by "padding" the braces' escape characters. (e.g. changing `"\{"` to `"\\\{"`)